# set .htpasswd with bash expect

Tags: bash, expect, .htpasswd

I'm trying to automate setting a user's password in .htpasswd for Apache, but this script doesn't seem to actually set the password. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD=`tr -dc a-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 10`

cat << EOF | /usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/htpasswd -c /var/.htpasswd testuser
expect "assword:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect "assword:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
EOF

echo -e "\nPassword set to: $PASSWORD\n"
```

Comment: Hahaha, yeah I was messing around with parsing earlier and forgot that there :P

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a password on the command line using the `-b` flag.

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD=`tr -dc a-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 10`
htpasswd -cb /var/.htpasswd testuser $PASSWORD
echo Password set to: $PASSWORD

# output:
# Adding password for user testuser
# Password set to: gzu00n4lp8
```

For clarification, here's a version using `expect`:

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD=`tr -dc a-z0-9_ < /dev/urandom | head -c 10`

expect << EOF
spawn htpasswd -c /var/.htpasswd testuser          
expect { 
    "New password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r"; exp_continue }
    "Re-type new password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r"; exp_continue }    
}                      
EOF  

echo Password set to: $PASSWORD
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman, thank you! This works perfectly. Do you have any idea why my script didn't work? Just curious what I did wrong.

Comment: There are a few syntax problems.  I played around with it and came up with an `expect` version.